# Moving forms between "organisations" in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to move a form from one "organisation" to another? Or copy the form to another "organization"?

Answer (score 1):

We are working on this for our April release.  Our goal is to support copying forms between any organization by sharing the form design via a link.

In a subsequent release we will add support for moving forms and entries between organizations, but this is actually a much bigger deal, as we carefully segment organization data to keep it private, so moving entries and files will actually be much more difficult than just moving form designs.

Comment: We released support for copying forms between organizations on April 28th.  Please read our [help documentation](http://help.cognitoforms.com/copying-forms) for more details on how this works.